# Edit woocommerce external url

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I need help on editing the WC external product URL, 
i want to change the button type (html) into 
`<button data-sell-product="product-id">Buy text</button>` 
This is how my content-product.php looks : 
`>

```
/**
 * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );

/**
 * woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

/**
 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );

/**
 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close - 5
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
?>
```

`
I tried from the dashboard but i need to edit in the HTML too.
So instead setting an URL from the edit product dashboard i will just need to add the product id. 
Can someone help me in which file i can find this to edit?

Comment: If you want to change the button that is in the `woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart()` which calls the [`loop/add-to-cart.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/loop/add-to-cart.php) template. You could either override that template or filter [`woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/loop/add-to-cart.php#L25).

Comment: `echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
 sprintf( ' <button data-selly-product="%s">Pay</button>',
  esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
  
  esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
  esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
 ),` I tryed like this but its only displaying one product in the shop page.

Comment: `echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
 sprintf( '<button data-selly-product="%s" class="%s">%s</button>
  ',
  esc_attr( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
  esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
  esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
 ),` Alright its working like this the modal is opening but from the dashboard when i add the product ID it automaticly adds http:// to it so its not working properly. How can i edit that too?

Comment: "from the dashboard when i add the product ID it automaticly adds http://" I don't know what you mean by that? Can you explain? Also, please edit your question with code, it's really hard to read code in the comments.

Comment: What i am trying to do is instead of the product URL i just need to add the product ID from selly.gg. The button is working when i press it, the modal i shown but to work properly it only needs to store the product id which i add. But when i add the product it adds http:// . I dont need that since with that my modal is not working. http://prntscr.com/f22iko Here is the input that i need modified. I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Because you are filling the first text replace with `$product->add_to_cart_url()` which will be a URL. You should maybe add a new meta field in the admin to caputre the selly.gg product ID and then filter the `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link` to insert that product ID.

Comment: I understand that but i have never added custom meta fields. I am unsure on how to do that..

Answer (score 0):

here's my 3 part approach. First you need to add a new text input to the product metabox. Then you need to save that data. This is where you will enter the selly.gg ID. Finally, you will filter the add to cart link to convert it to a button and pass it the ID you saved in the first two steps. It should look something like this, but I didn't test it so be wary of typos.

```
/*
 * Add text inputs to product metabox
 *
 * @return print HTML
 * @since 1.0
 */
function so_43684081_add_to_metabox(){
    global $post;

    $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );

    // if variable billing is enabled, continue to show options. otherwise, deprecate
    $show_billing_period_options = wc_string_to_bool( $product->get_meta( '_variable_billing' ) );

    echo '<div class="options_group show_if_external">';

        woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
            'id' => '_selly_id',
            'label' => __( 'Selly.gg Product ID', 'your-plugin' ),
        ) );

    echo '</div>';

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'so_43684081_add_to_metabox' );




/*
 * Save extra meta info
 *
 * @param object $post
 * @return void
 */
function so_43684081_save_product_meta( $product ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['_selly_id'] ) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data( '_selly_id', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_selly_id'] ) );
    } else {
        $product->delete_meta_data( '_selly_id' );
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'so_43684081_save_product_meta' );


/*
 * Modify the external link
 *
 * @param object $post
 * @return void
 */
function so_43684081_loop_add_to_cart_link( $link, $product ) {  

    if( $product->is_type( 'external' ) ) {
        $link = sprintf( '<button data-selly-product="%s" class="%s">%s</button>',
            esc_attr( $product->get_meta( '_selly_id' ) ),
            esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
            esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
        );
    }
    return $link;

add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'so_43684081_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: For testing that's fine. But this should really be a plugin.

Comment: I managed to add the fields in my admin dashboard using a plugin. I can now add the product id.  But how to use it inside `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link` This is how am supossed to access it but i dont know how to use it on the data-selly-product.
`$my_admin_field_val = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "wccaf_your_admin_field_name", true );`

Comment: Did my function for that not work? Anyway, you'd replace `$product->get_meta( '_selly_id' )` with your code, but you will also need to `global $post` since I'm not calling it anywhere.